# Is my website www or without www subdomain?

Tags: dns, subdomain

This seems like a really stupid question, but I can't tell if my website uses the www subdomain or without.

I purchased an expired domain a month ago and set up Google Webmastertools with a sitemap and all. It's indexed, but when searching for the website name, it's no where to be found. Webmastertools says that 'no data is available.' The support states that the www subdomain may be a factor.

How can I verify this? I've used info: domain.com, site: domain.com, info: www.domain.com and site: www.domain.com It pulls up domain.com

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. Need to find whether the both www and non-www are pointing to same IP address. For this, Open command prompt (click start button >> run >> provide code "cmd"). Once command prompt is launched, then run the code "Ping domain.com" you can find a IP address and then run "ping www.domain.com" and you get another IP address. If both IPs are different then you have setup A record in DNS.
2. If they are same IP address, non-www need to redirect www or www redirect to non-www. To find this, provide both URLS on http://www.redirect-checker.org/ find out which are getting 200 status. The 200 status URL are need to be added on webmastertool.

Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Who is handling the DNS? If you own domain.com, the www. is (as you said) a subdomain.

You can register any subdomain you want as long as you are pointing it to somewhere. For example if I set up domain.com with DNS pointing to the hosting I would create an A record for the subdomain www that points to the same IP address.

From there I would check the Host server and (I use IIS) make sure that the bindings for the domain are set up, usually I bind it to www.domain.com as default and then just send domain.com there.

I hope this helps answer your question